# Capture javascript errors

Tags: javascript, delphi, debugging, internet-explorer, twebbrowser

I'd like to attach a debugger to a TWebBrowser control. I'm currently using Delphi.

The functionality I'm looking for is to capture javascript errors as well as being able to pause script execution and step through it (or similar).

Having using this control for some time, I can't for the life of me figure this one out. Problem is all this dynamic API is kind of a black box and difficult to find what I need.

When it comes to JS errors, I'm only able to capture the notorious Exception EOleException 80020101.

If you know anything about this, don't hesitate to put it forward **(even if in VB or .NET)**!

**Note:** [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Script_Debugger) does this job perfectly, anyone knows how they did it?

Comment: Surely you'd be better off debugging the JavaScript in a real browser rather than an embedded one. I don't know what tools exist for IE, but there must be some.

Comment: @David - I agree, but this is for a pet project where "The Browser" is the one I'm embedding - the code final code is not intended to work elsewhere, neither in websites. Think of it like a small pet (educational) IDE.

Comment: Can't you embed Microsoft Script Debugger? I'm assuming since you mention it that you are building your own tool and want its users to be able to debug their scripts.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I just started looking into how MSD works. I'd gladly embed it if it stayed hidden as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot all about this question, the answer's here:
[WebBrowser (MSIE) - Capture JS Errors using Exec of IOleCommandTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450514/webbrowser-msie-capture-js-errors-using-exec-of-iolecommandtarget)