# Is there a way to track Internet Explorer Error messages from the WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to track error messages in a webBrowser control?  For example, in Firefox or Internet Explorer, I can look at the console output for Javascript errors.  Is there a way to track those errors from within the application?

Comment: have u tried `window.onerror` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two related Microsoft KB articles:

- "[How to handle script errors as a WebBrowser control host](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261003/en-us)"
- "[Script error notification is not sent to Exec method of WebBrowser Host](https://expertreplies.com/script-error-notification-is-not-sent-to-exec-method-of-webbrowser-host/)"

Although these are related to unmanaged C++ code, you should be able to adopt these for the C# web browser control, too.

Another article suggests to subscribe to the `onerror` event:

```
m_htmlDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)axWebBrowser1.Document;
HTMLWindowEvents2_Event onErrorEvent;
onErrorEvent = (HTMLWindowEvents2_Event)m_htmlDoc.parentWindow;
onErrorEvent.onerror += new
HTMLWindowEvents2_onerrorEventHandler(myHTMLWindowEvents2_onerror);
```

And finally, there is [a similar SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450514/webbrowser-msie-capture-js-errors-using-exec-of-iolecommandtarget) related to Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

use **window.onerror** event, something like

```
window.onerror=function(msg, url, linenumber){
   alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber)
   return true
}
```

Comment: This would require to change the _content_ of what is being displayed in the WebBrowser control. Is this really a suitable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of IE have a developer toolbar but sadly its not quite as good as Firebug or Web Inspector but thankfully we do have Firebug lite (http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) which can help out with most things.